# My friend needs me to act as a current landlord

Tags: real-estate

My friend is having a hard time renting because she has never lived on her own. Everywhere she's gone they said she has to show 3 years rental history. I'm not coming doing this I feel it's fraud. I need something that I can show her so she'll believe I could get into trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the management of an interpersonal relationship, not the law or legal process.

Comment: It sounds like she has figured out the interpersonal aspect and is now looking for support for the proposition that falsifying a rental agreement is against the law.

Comment: Dawn Wadsworth: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: While I get some of the gist of the question, it is still too fuzzy in my mind to offer an answer to. The details of what is being asked and what the facts actually are do not seem sufficiently clear.

Comment: @ohwilleke the question seems to me to be "my friend doesn't believe that it would be risky for me to claim falsely that I am her current landlord.  What can I show or tell my friend to demonstrate to her that I could in fact get into serious trouble for doing that?"  Dawn, if this is incorrect, of course please say so.

Answer (score 1):

Fraud is deliberate deception to secure unfair or unlawful gain - what she is proposing is fraud.

It’s a crime for which you could both go to jail, however, prosecution is unlikely.

A greater risk is that if she fails to pay the rent or wrecks the place, the landlord can sue you for the loss. Of course, a real referee can be sued for negligent misstatement so, even if you were her landlord, the reference should disclose *everything*: the good and the bad.

If you are willing to be on the hook for her debts, a better and legal way to help her is to offer to stand guarantor for her.